# What does "all over" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

All over a place means in every part of it, but in this context, what does it mean?

> 27 min: Burnley are **all over** Everton, who are all over the place! Gudmundsson strides down the middle and curls a low drive onto the base of the left-hand post and away! So unlucky not to make it three.

Comment: First of all, you need to repeat the fact that this is football. to be all over someone = to dominate them. Also, you should check that great glossary I gave you, it has this in there and you might want to show some appreciation about "cushion"....

Comment: You've asked over 50 questions on this site so far, but only accepted an answer to one of them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because too many football questions from this person already.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry but that's not a valid reason for closure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a football-specific term, but it is chiefly British.

To [be all over something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-all-over-it) mean to be successfully in control of something. So, in the context of a game, it means that you are winning, perhaps without too much effort. It also often implies preparedness, that you were in control from the start.